# Move Linux Partitions, Dual Boot with windows

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos, parted

I'm not thinking about Expand Linux Partitions...
I need Shrink (one, the larger) and move it (two, with the swap)...

Here my HD from Windows View (Disk Management)

[image]

Now, I want to reduce the last partition (with CenOS), and move the two partitions...

Like image (*check `Unallocated` is bigger and move the Linux partitions to Right*):

[image]

I need to obtain a only **one bigger** partition between (Windows and Linux Partitions).

Here View from CentOS using `gparted`

[image]

And Warnings from Linux

```
# gparted
======================
libparted : 2.1
======================
WARNING: the kernel failed to re-read the partition table on /dev/sdb (Device or resource busy).  As a result, it may not reflect all of your changes until after reboot.
WARNING: the kernel failed to re-read the partition table on /dev/sdb (Device or resource busy).  As a result, it may not reflect all of your changes until after reboot.
# partprobe
Warning: WARNING: the kernel failed to re-read the partition table on /dev/sdb (Device or resource busy).  As a result, it may not reflect all of your changes until after reboot.
#
```

**What Recommendations apply for this?**

**What steps are needed (it's not simply Shrinking)?**

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do, please proof read you question, and improve clarity. (I think that the only bit I got is that you are not trying to shrink a partition)

Comment: I want to expand the Unallocated Space (from 51.0GB to 91.02GB) taking Bytes from Linux Partition (142.09GB)

Comment: You won't be able to put anything in the unallocated space since you already have the maximum number of partitions (3 primary + 1 extended).

Comment: @curtis could not the extended partition or the 3rd primary be extended into it.

Comment: Yes it could, sorry... I was thinking about creating a new partition.

Comment: Dear colleagues, I regret to inform you that I damaged the bootloader (using `gparted`), only a cursor appears on the fourth row flashing and no more.

Answer (score 0):

How to do it using gparted.

- first back-up your data, then
- shrink `/dev/sdb6` to the right.
- move `/dev/sdb5` to the right.
- (Now pay attention to what @curtis said)
- if you will next extend `/dev/sdb3` into the space then

  - shrink `/dev/sdb4` (the extended partition) to the right.
  - extend `/dev/sdb3` into space.
  - click apply
- else if you will next add a new partition then

  - add new partition to `/dev/sdb4` (the extended partition)
  - click apply
- else

  - error